# May amphtml link URLs contain a GET query string?

Tags: amp-html

I've set up my amphtml page variants to show when `?v=amp` is present in the URL.

Is having a GET query string in the amphtml URL valid?

Comment: You can also verify the page by adding "#development=1" to the URL and checking the DevTools console for any validation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've confirmed (as my pages with query strings have begun appearing in AMP results) that amphtml URLs with query strings are valid.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any issues serving content dynamically based on the query string.